# GridView auto recycle views?

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, scroll, android-gridview

I have a empty `GridView` where I use Drag and Drop to add some images, but I'm having truble with it, because its eliminating or placing the images in wrong places if the keyboard is called or I scroll the GridView.

For example:

This is the empty `GridView`. I can't insert image, or don't know how to. So I will try to do it like this

```
[  ][  ][  ][  ][  ]
[  ][  ][  ][  ][  ]
[  ][  ][  ][  ][  ]
[  ][  ][  ][  ][  ]
```

Then I use Drag and Drop and I add some pics (Numbers are pics)

```
[ 1][  ][  ][ 4][  ]
[  ][  ][  ][  ][  ]
[  ][  ][ 2][  ][ 5]
[  ][ 3][  ][  ][  ]
```

Then I click a button to add a integer so I call other class with other `xml` having an `EditText` and if I click it to write the integer the keyboard will popup and the `GridView` will then do something like this when I get back to it.

```
[  ][  ][  ][  ][  ]
[ 2][  ][ 3][  ][  ]
[  ][  ][  ][ 4][  ]
[ 1][ 5][  ][  ][  ]
```

Same if I scroll it. I hope I have been clear.

Comment: Common guys, someone have to know something...

Comment: Check out [this project on GitHub](https://github.com/thquinn/DraggableGridView), I think it will help you with what you are trying to accomplish. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Well I downloaded it and installed it on my phone (To check if it works) and it works. So give me like 4-5 days to study the code and will report back. Thank you!!

Comment: Are you still having trouble with this? If not, you may answer the question yourself or delete it.

Comment: Still getting problems, I'm about to rewrite all the code again to see if I can solve it, but its to much code. Also the answer from Asok doesn't do the problem, but its odd because it have a simple code nothing special to make them stay at the place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Funny and stupid thing, it got fixed with making the child width `fill_parent`.